# Change color of active file tab in WebStorm 9

Tags: colors, themes, webstorm

Is there a way to change the color of the active tab in WebStorm 9?

I know you can change the text based on different states, but I want to look up and quickly see where the hell I am. There must be a way because the color themes obviously change them.

If you know that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it can't be changed - this color is a part of IDE l&f and thus is hardcoded. Please vote for [IDEA-126775](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126775) to increase its priority and be notified about updates.

Please also check this thread: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5532304#5532304 - you might find the suggestions helpful